# Google search keywords containing special characters

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to extract google search urls for input search keywords using selenium. However the input has special characters like / and - and the google search output strips these characters when generating results. Is there an option to make it read these special characters by default without stripping them. Basically only those urls which match the exact input search keyword for eg, '/old-bag' should be displayed. What changes should be done to get search results for exact keyword with special characters

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


with open("Output.txt", 'w') as text_file:
    print('Output', file=text_file)
df = pd.read_csv("Input.txt",encoding="utf-8",dtype=str)
count=0
hitid=0
for i in df['Input']:
    count = count + 1
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Ani\Downloads\geckodriver.exe')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get("https://www.google.fr/")
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'gLFyf gsfi')]")
    search_field.clear()
    search_field.send_keys('"%s"'%(i))
    search_field.submit()
    captcha = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//form[@id='captcha-form']")
    if captcha:
        print('captcha page')
        hitid = hitid + 1
        break
    else:
        for _ in range(5):
            elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'yuRUbf')]//a[@href[not(contains(.,'/t5/') or contains(.,'/attachments/') or contains(.,'webcache') or contains(.,'start='))]][not(contains(.,'Translate this page'))][normalize-space()]")
            if len(elements) == 0:
                print('No search results')
                break
            else:
                for e in elements:
                    with open("Output.txt", "a") as text_file:
                        print(e.get_attribute("href"), file=text_file)
                next_page = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(@class,'YyVfkd')]//following-sibling::td") # note find_elements with an 's'
                if not(next_page):
                    break
                next_page[0].click()    
    driver.close()
driver.quit()
print('Run completed')
if(hitid == 1):
    print('captcha page hit')
```